# Javascript fill function not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fill javascript array. Is it possible?

```
var array = new Array(10);
array.fill(10,1,5);
```

Comment: It is new ES6 feature http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Alexander You might as well make an answer

Comment: The good thing is DOC implements the polyfill, so what is the point of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is new [ES6 feature](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6) (*in the table open Array.prototype methods*)

If browser does not support this feature you can use this [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/d5648c89420eb333904c)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is part of the [ECMAScript 6 proposal](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.fill).

this is a polyfill that you can use to provide the same functionality until support comes to all browsers

```
if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
  Array.prototype.fill = function(value) {

    // Steps 1-2.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);

    // Steps 3-5.
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // Steps 6-7.
    var start = arguments[1];
    var relativeStart = start >> 0;

    // Step 8.
    var k = relativeStart < 0 ?
      Math.max(len + relativeStart, 0) :
      Math.min(relativeStart, len);

    // Steps 9-10.
    var end = arguments[2];
    var relativeEnd = end === undefined ?
      len : end >> 0;

    // Step 11.
    var final = relativeEnd < 0 ?
      Math.max(len + relativeEnd, 0) :
      Math.min(relativeEnd, len);

    // Step 12.
    while (k < final) {
      O[k] = value;
      k++;
    }

    // Step 13.
    return O;
  };
}
```